# MediaElement plays sound 2 times after changing source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app, and I am having an issue I cannot work out.
I looked up every code on the internet I could find and I've been trying to figure out the source of the problem for hours, but with no success.
Let's take a simple code:

xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App8.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App8"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid>
            <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement1" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App8
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;

            MediaElement1.MediaOpened += MediaElement1_MediaOpened;
        }

        void MediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement1.Play();
        }


        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement1.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/SampleSets/First/clap_01.mp3");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I am clicking the button, then from time to time the sound is being played twice. Sometimes is after a first click, sometimes after 10 of them. I just want to emphasize that this is just simple code to show what my problem is and I do not really want to change the Source of the MediaElement to the same again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've tried the problem seems to occur (sometimes) while running on Emulator.

While I was tesing it on a device, I couldn't reproduce the same behaviour.

Comment: I tried solution like this and unfortunately it doesn't work (I also tried it once more a minute ago, just to be sure). I know that default value is true and that's why I set the AutoPlay to false in the xaml. I don't really understand what you mean by saying : "You may also try to remove your MediaElement1.Play(); from MediaElement1_MediaOpened event". If I do that there will be no sound. Do you mean there is some better equivalent?

Comment: @RetSet Nah, I've missed Autoplay you had set in xaml. I've just tested the sample code, and in fact I can also hear short double sound while running on emulator, but when I've tried on a device, there was no such a problem. Do you also suffer the problem on a device?

Comment: @RetSet By removing `Play()`, I meant the situation when your `Autoplay == true`, then MediaElement would start just after setting the source. But it doesn't matter as I've said in previous comment.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have access to the device right now. Each problem I run into lately, was showing up on both emulator and device. I sure hope it will be different with this one. Thanks for pointing that out, I will check it out as soon as I can.

Comment: @RetSet I've tested it only 5 x 20 button clicks, and the problem occured in my case only on Emuloator. I'm also curious if it will be similar with other device. It's hard to tell what could be the other reason, hence the code seems to be ok. Give me a sign if I have to leave/delete the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Today I tested it on Nokia Lumia 820 and there was no problem, so it is probably just some emulator bug. You should definitely leave this answer :D

Comment: @RetSet The same Phone I've tested. But I also think its strictly connected to emulator, maybe not a bug, but some problem with loading media file by emulator and then processing it (some delay?). Thanks for the info.